# RANK() Over Partition BY not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partitioning

When I run the code below the ROWID is always 1.
I need to the ID to start at 1 for each item with the same **Credit Value**.

```
;WITH CTETotal AS (SELECT
     TranRegion
    ,TranCustomer
    ,TranDocNo
    ,SUM(TranSale) 'CreditValue'
FROM dbo.Transactions

LEFT JOIN customers AS C 
      ON custregion = tranregion 
      AND custnumber = trancustomer
LEFT JOIN products AS P
      ON prodcode = tranprodcode

GROUP BY
TranRegion
,TranCustomer
,TranDocNo)

SELECT
       r.RegionDesc
      ,suppcodedesc
      ,t.tranreason as [Reason]
      ,t.trandocno as [Document Number]
      ,sum(tranqty) as Qty
      ,sum(tranmass) as Mass
      ,sum(transale) as Sale
      ,cte.CreditValue AS 'Credit Value'
      ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cte.CreditValue ORDER BY cte.CreditValue)AS ROWID

FROM transactions t

LEFT JOIN dbo.Regions AS r    
      ON r.RegionCode = TranRegion  

LEFT JOIN CTETotal AS cte
      ON cte.TranRegion = t.TranRegion
      AND cte.TranCustomer = t.TranCustomer
      AND cte.TranDocNo = t.TranDocNo

GROUP BY 
       r.RegionDesc
      ,suppcodedesc
      ,t.tranreason
      ,t.trandocno
      ,cte.CreditValue

ORDER BY CreditValue ASC
```

**EDIT**

All the credit values with 400 must have the ROWID set to 1. And all the credit values with 200 must have the ROWID set to 2. And so on and so on.

Comment: And within each CreditValue, how do you want the rows to be ordered?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have all unique CreditValues? You may need to round the value.

Comment: `PARTITION BY cte.CreditValue ORDER BY { what column represents item? }` Now it is always 1 because order by value is always the same per partition.

Comment: What are 400 and 200 ? Where have they came from?

Comment: Try `dense_rank() over(order by cte.CreditValue desc)`. Does it do what you want?

Comment: 400 and 200 are examples of the total Credit Value would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
with cte (item,CreditValue)
as
(
select 'a',8 as CreditValue union all
select 'b',18 union all
select 'a',8 union all
select 'b',18 union all
select 'a',8 
) 
select CreditValue,dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY item)AS ROWID from cte
```

Result

```
CreditValue ROWID
----------- --------------------
8           1
8           1
8           1
18          2
18          2
```

In your code replace

```
,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cte.CreditValue ORDER BY cte.CreditValue)AS ROWID
```

by

```
,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cte.CreditValue)AS ROWID
```

Answer (score 3):

You just don't have to use `PARTITION`, just `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cte.CreditValue)`

Comment: My first set of Credit Values do have the rowID of 1, but the second set have 10, third set have 11, and last set have 26.

Comment: Sorry, use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `RANK`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY clause

you have to partition it by item not by CreditValue

Comment: I have tried that, does not work. All the credit values with 400 must have the ROWID set to 1. And all the credit values with 200 must have the ROWID set to 2. And so on and so on.

Comment: See my reply. You need to use dense_rank()

Comment: @Madhivanan: Thanks Mahivanan... I didnt get the question :(    +1 for you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cte.CreditValue ORDER BY cte.RegionDesc)AS ROWID

Answer (score 0):

## Edit: The issue here isn't actually the nesting of the subquery, it's potentially based on `partition by` having columns that truly make each row unique (or 1)

Rather than ranking within your complex query like this

```sql
select 
   rank() over(partition by...),
   *
from
   data_source
join table1
join table2
join table3
join table4
order by
   some_column
```

Try `rank()` or `row_number()` on the resulting data set, not within it.

For example, using the query above, remove `rank()` and implement it this way:

```sql
select
   rank() over(partition by...),
   results.*
from (
    select 
       *
    from
       data_source
    join table1
    join table2
    join table3
    join table4
    order by
       some_column
) as results
```